# MySQL how to decrease value by 1 with a trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

I'm building a simple videogame store inventory and sales database with MySQL.
At the moment I have an Inventory table:

```
game_id      count
1            5
2            2
3            1
4            7
```

and a sales table

```
game_id      price     otherstuff 
3            xxx       xxxxx
2            xxxx      xxxxxxxx
```

I would like to create a trigger that checks what game_id is added to the sales table. Then decreases the count by -1 in the inventory table. I would guess its "After update".

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `sales_AFTER_INSERT` AFTER INSERT ON `sales` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
update inventory set count = count-1 where game_id = game_id;
END
```

After testing this script it just decreases every game_id count by -1 everytime I insert some new sales.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have incorrect `game_id` in your query. If you want to get `game_id` from a modified record you should use `NEW.game_id`

```
CREATE DEFINER =`root`@`localhost`
  TRIGGER `sales_AFTER_INSERT`
  AFTER INSERT
  ON `sales`
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  UPDATE inventory SET count = count - 1 WHERE game_id = NEW.game_id;
END
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you! I should have looked more into the documentations of Triggers and SQL.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use NEW:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` 
   TRIGGER `sales_AFTER_INSERT` 
   AFTER INSERT ON `sales` FOR EACH ROW 
   BEGIN
        update inventory set count = count-1 where game_id = new.game_id;
END
```